# Apply a color gradient to lines of a tabularx

Tags: tabularx, gradient

I am trying to apply a color gradient to the horizontal lines of a tabularx environment. I have a two-column tabularx in which I want the second column to be lined with left-to-right color gradient horizontal lines (pictured below).

[image]

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Please see the MWE below.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily{\greekfonttt}{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{greek}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}    
    {\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
                ΙΔΡΥΜΑ & First line \\ \arrayrulecolor{red} \cline{2-2}
                ΣΧΟΛΗ & Second line \\ \arrayrulecolor{red} \cline{2-2}
            \end{tabularx}
    }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That package provides environment similar to the classical environments `{tabular}` and `{tabularx}` but which creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columsn. It's possible to use those nodes to draw with Tikz whatever rule you want after the construction of the array (in the `\CodeAfter`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily{\greekfonttt}{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{greek}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}    
{
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{rX}
    ΙΔΡΥΜΑ & First line \\ 
    ΣΧΟΛΗ & Second line \\ 
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [left color = red]
           ([yshift=0.5\arrayrulewidth]2-|2) rectangle 
           ([yshift=-0.5\arrayrulewidth]2-|last) ; 
    \path [left color = red]
           ([yshift=0.5\arrayrulewidth]3-|2) rectangle 
           ([yshift=-0.5\arrayrulewidth]3-|last) ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabularX}
}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

---

In fact, with `nicematrix`, it's also possible to write a command `\MyHrule` to use at the beginning of a row in the `{NiceTabular}`. That command will write in the `\CodeAfter` the correct instructions to draw the rule as wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily{\greekfonttt}{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{greek}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__AlexSt_MyRule:n
  {
    \tikz \path [left~color = red]
               ([yshift=0.5\arrayrulewidth]#1-|2) rectangle 
               ([yshift=-0.5\arrayrulewidth]#1-|last) ; 
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \MyRule { }
 {
   \noalign 
     { 
       \skip_vertical:N \arrayrulewidth 
       \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl 
         { \__AlexSt_MyRule:n { \int_eval:n { \int_use:c { c@iRow } + 1 } } }
     }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}    
{
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{rX}
  ΙΔΡΥΜΑ & First line \\ 
  \MyRule
  ΣΧΟΛΗ & Second line \\ 
  \MyRule
\end{NiceTabularX}
}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, with that programmation, vertical space is reserved for the rules (as does the classical `\hline` of `array`).

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I cannot get this to compile. I'm getting a whole load of errors including "pgf Error: No shape named 'last' is known" for example. When you say several compilations, roughly how many would suffice?

Comment: You probably don't have the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation.  If you use Overleaf, consider that Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`.

Comment: For the right number of compilations, several tools such, as `latexmk`, do successive compilations until the `aux` file keeps unchanged (that's the right criteria).

Comment: After updating my TeX distribution and installing ```latex-tools``` for MikTex, it finally worked! Thanks